# Splitting large CSV file stops when encountering NUL character

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a 200Mb CSV file that I am splitting using the code below. All working fine but today the batch file stopped processing when it came across lines that contained NUL values (we opened up the large file in Notepad++)

[image]

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set limit=200000
set file=test.csv
set lineCounter=1
set filenameCounter=1

set name=
set extension=
for %%a in (%file%) do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "extension=%%~xa"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    set splitFile=!name!-part!filenameCounter!!extension!
    if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
        set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1
        set lineCounter=1
        echo Created !splitFile!.
    )
    echo %%a>> !splitFile!

    set /a lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1
)
pause
```

Any advice on how to get around this issue? Unfortunately we are just limited to using Windows and the Command Prompt.

Comment: There's probably nothing you can do to solve the problem using just Windows batch-files.

Comment: Cracking. Thanks Ross Ridge Crisp

Comment: what is format of your csv file? This one seems to be semicolon delimited, meaning it is not in csv format.

Comment: CSV files are text files which contain only a very small set of control characters. The `NUL` character, _(ASCII 0)_, is not one of the allowed control characters. The appropriate fix is to ask the producer of the CSV to provide it without the invalid characters, _probably by using an appropriate character encoding_.

Comment: A semicolon delimited file can be treated and named as a CSV file @GerhardBarnard regardless, we'd still have this issue if it was commas

Comment: Can we do a try/exception so if we come across a line with this in, we ignore and move onto next?

Comment: If you can use 3rd-party utilities like `(g)awk` or `sed` then you could pre-process the file to eliminate nulls. Yes, I know you said windows and command-prompt only, but this could mean "no high-level languages" not "no 3rd-party utilities"